# Failing to run command in makefile project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem when i try to build my makefile project within Eclipse on Linux OS. Whole makefile executes fine except for the last command which is `unsimgcr -pd input output`. I get an error `/bin/bash: unsimgcr: command not found`.

The weirdest thing is that if i run make command from linux terminal the makefile executes fine no problems. I think I should set something within Eclipse IDE, but I don't know how and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely unsimgcr is in your path when you run it from the command line but not in the path when run from eclipse.  Either fix the path issues, or put an absolute path to unsimgcr in the make file.

Comment: So Eclipse must have its own PATH to set somewhere?